# Remove the end of a string where a pattern begins PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm retrieving a string and I want to remove the remainder of the string after the words "read more".

eg

$str = 'a big long description about something, read more about something over at another website';

I don't want to use substr as the length of the data can vary.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could `explode` on "read more" and take the first part. `$str = explode('read more',$str)[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strstr($str, 'read more', true)`

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr), like so:

```
$firtpart = substr($str, 0, strpos($str,'read more'));
```

Or use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split the string into two parts and take the first part:

```
list($firtpart) = explode('read more', $str);
```

Or even use a regular expression:

```
$firtpart = preg_replace("/read more.*$/", '', $str);
```